# Probability when selecting from 2 populations with different medians

Tags: probability, sampling, median

Given differing median values for two populations, what is the probability that a randomly selected person from the higher-median population will have a higher value than someone from the lower-median population? (I think I need to assume the populations are of similar size)

Comment: 1) Do you have any information other than the median 2) This sounds a bit like a homework question, for which we have special rules. Could you clarify if it is, and add the self-study tag if so?

Comment: It's not a homework question. It came up in a debate about how to interpret data about differences in pay between gender.

Comment: Thanks. Could you address the first question, and also explain what you mean by "*will represent the higher metric*"

Comment: The population sizes are roughly equal, and I want to know the probability that for a given man, woman pair, the man's income will be higher, given men's median income is higher.

Comment: @RobinAndrews The median is not enough information. It could also be more likely for the woman's income to be higher.

Comment: Are you sure? It's the probability that I am trying to ascertain from the available data, which is on the median income of the two populations, so that looks like it would involve circular reasoning to me.

Comment: I have added an answer which describes my understanding.

Comment: I ran a simulation, and it looks like the bigger the difference in median, the higher the probability of selecting a representative of the population with the greater median value. Maybe obvious, but not to me yet. with 30k vs 20k and sd of 10k for both, there was roughly an 85% chance.

Comment: To run a simulation, you need to make assumptions about distribution, variance and skewness that will affect that probability. If you are happy to make such assumptions, it's worth stating them in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The median is not enough information. It could even be more likely for the woman's income to be higher.

Consider the following example.

[image]

This figure is an example histogram for the income of the two populations "men" (blue) and "women" (red). Clearly, the median of men is higher than the one of women, yet if you randomly choose a (man, woman) pair, it is more likely that the woman is having a higher income.

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting this graph. Could you possibly provide a summary of what is represented by the various components?

Comment: It shows a possible histogram for the income distribution in men and women. Could you point out what exactly is unclear?

Comment: The little medians in the middle, for example? And the fact that all the other bars are the same height. I'm something of an amateur so although I understand the basics, I can't really see what is happening in this chart. Also, what does count represent?

Comment: I don't see how the median for women could be lower than the median for men based on these histograms.

Comment: @mkt The four larger blocks have all the same mass, and the tiny blocks in the middle make sure that the median of women is slightly less than that of men.

Comment: @mkt I just want to point out that the median of e.g. 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 10, 10 would be 2.

Comment: (+1) Thanks, that is helpful and you're right. I thought the little block in the middle was just indicating the median, not that it was part of the histogram. Perhaps worth separating them (and making them the same width as the other bars) to make this clear?

Comment: @mkt Thanks for the advice, I changed the figure. I enlarged the width of the smaller blocks, and I also removed the word "medians", which might have been adding to the confusion.

Comment: @RobinAndrews This is a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), which could be understood as some discretization of the probability density. One often partitions the values into intervals, or "bins" (called "binning"), and the bars over the intervals have as height the number of data points in this interval. The resulting bar plot is proportional to a discrete approximation of the pdf. Here, we have two histograms (women, men) in one plot. Also, recall the difference between mean and median to understand this example. Please let me know if something is left unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not contain enough information.

In general, if you have 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$, corresponding to 2 independent observations of your distributions, you should compute $\mathbb{P}\left(X>Y\right)$. This depends on the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. In order to do compute that, you need to have either:

- Assumptions about these distributions. Ex: Pareto distribution with parameters $p_X$ and $p_Y$ for instance.
- Empirical distributions/samples for your populations.

Depending on what you have on hand, you can compute a simple analytical formula to solve your problem (only with "nice" distributions), or use simulations to estimate your probabilities.

EDIT following your comments and your new question:

I do not think that you will be able to get any reasonable estimate with only 2 medians. If you have $m_Y>m_X$ (where $m$ represents the median, the only estimate you will be able to get is $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)\geq\frac{1}{2}$ in my opinion. **(for some distributions, @frank was able to get a counterexample)** Take these 2 extreme examples:

1. $X=m_X, Y=m_Y$, i.e., there is no variations, every man has the same salary, same for women. Then you will have $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)=1$.
2. The standard deviations of the distributions are huge compared to the median, like 100 times the median (for example). Then, these variations in the individual distributions will overweight the difference between the medians, and you might get close to $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)=\frac{1}{2}$.

In general, remember that $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)=\mathbb{P}(Y-X>0)$. So you are interested in the **distribution** of $Y-X$. It is impossible to get information about this distribution without information about the **individual distributions** of $X$, $Y$, and their dependencies (no dependency in your case). Some tricks might exist with some assumptions/estimates of the standard deviation of the distributions, but that's it. You cannot build a good estimate without good input data. In your case, your data is insufficient in my opinion.

Comment: Are you able to help me calculate this probability with the data under "The headline measure for the gender pay gap" in this link please https://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/earningsandworkinghours/articles/understandingthegenderpaygapintheuk/2018-01-17 ?

Comment: Do you mean with the plot with the evolution medians of male/female income ? No, a couple of medians is not enough. You need more than that, like samples, or at least some empirical description of the distributions (like quantiles). Or have I missed the data you were refering to?

Comment: I've made another question as this was too abstract, I think. Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582753/probability-of-higher-hourly-earnings-by-gender-from-uk-data

Comment: I checked your new question, and I confirm that you will not be able to estimate such a probability with this kind of data.

Comment: Not even a ballpark figure? Can you explain why please?

Comment: I edited my answer to try to explain further.

Comment: Is there not enough generally accepted contextual understanding to make an estimate somewhat valid, as long as reasonable assumptions used are stated?

Comment: I do not think so.