# Probability of higher hourly earnings by gender from UK data

Tags: probability, median, inequality

I'm trying to find the probability that in the UK, in a male, female pair picked at random, the female will have the higher annual income.

I have following data from https://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/earningsandworkinghours/articles/understandingthegenderpaygapintheuk/2018-01-17

```
Year,Men's median hourly pay,Women's median hourly pay,Pay gap in median hourly pay(%)
2011    13.12   11.75   10.5
2012    13.27   12.01   9.5
2013    13.60   12.24   10.0
2014    13.61   12.30   9.6
2015    13.85   12.51   9.6
2016    14.16   12.82   9.4
2017    14.48   13.16   9.1
```

How do I go about calculating this probability please, say for 2017? It couldn't be as simple as it being the same as the "Pay gap in median hourly pay(%)" could it?

Comment: You can't get a definite answer from such limited information.  The very best you can do is state that this probability is between 0% and 75%.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about why this is so please? Also is any value in that range equally probable?

Comment: The *only* information supplied by the median (for any given year) is that half the population has a higher hourly pay and half has a lower hourly pay.  For instance, with a men's median of 14 and a women's median of 13 it's mathematically possible half the women make almost 0 and the other half make 13.01, while half the men make 13.99 and the other half make 15. It's also possible half the women make 12.99 and half make 99 while half the men make almost 0 and the other half make 14.01.  Those extremes lead to the 25/75% bounds.

Comment: (continued) Sure, both situations are implausible--but they demonstrate you must have additional data or make additional assumptions if you wish to narrow those bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of any reasonable assumptions and therefore give a plausible ballpark figure for the probably please?

Comment: Sure, but that's leaning too hard on the assumptions.  If this were my problem, I would consult detailed data from the UK Census.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the skill or the time to dig that deep. I was hoping for just a rough answer I could use in reasoning about the situation. One based on assumptions that are unlikely to be wildly wrong.

Comment: Even to make an extremely rough assumption you would need additional information.  For instance, you could assume the distributions are Lognormal (which often isn't a bad approximation for incomes) but the median only tells you their expectations, whereas you *must* have some information about their spreads in order to obtain an estimate of this probability.  Your data are just too limited.  You have three choices: (1) obtain some more information; (2) give up; (3) fabricate an answer.

Comment: I see you have already been told as much by several people in your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582669/probability-when-selecting-from-2-populations-with-different-medians -- no point in repeating those conversations here.

Comment: Quite a lot hinges on this answer as many people have some quite extreme views based on a misunderstanding of what can rightly be inferred from readily available data on the subject. Personally I expect some reasonable assumptions could be made from contextual knowledge, and if these were stated I don't think the answer would be useless, or "fabricated." I see edits have been made to an answer on the other question, but no actual viable ballpark figure suggested.